# Android how to finish activity from other process

Tags: android, android-activity, android-runonuithread

There are different app just call A and B,  I need to finish the activity in A when get the provider call from B, I found sometimes will fail, the activity no finish if do finish directly.

PS: the call thread is from B Main UI Thread, and I try to handle the finish action on A UI Thread the code like :

```
 runOnUiThread (
    new Runnable() {
        finish();
    }
 )
```

But the code is no work,too, the `Runnable` just no go.

Someone can help?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially please read the sections [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also want to use [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for reference.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you want to call an Activity in app A from another app? Can you expand on "there are different app"? Have you tried creating a method in activity A that finishes the Activity and can be called from B?

Comment: pass Activity A reference to Activity B then call finish with its reference activitya. finish(). It is also possible that activity A has killed by Android Application manager because of memory run out. At that time may be reference to Activity get null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `finish()` like this:

```
runOnUiThread (
  new Runnable(){
   ((YourActivity) Activity()).finish();
 }
)
```

Comment: thanks... but the code just like i do before...I cant find the different ..